# How to restrict certain strings from input in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to restrict certain string like `TEST,DUMMY` to be removed from text box entry, i did below code but not working

```
        <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" style="width:1000%">

                                                <input (input)="inputValidator($event)" matInput id="SiteId" formControlName="SiteId" placeholder="Enter Site Id" type="text" required />
                                            </mat-form-field>
```

In .ts file

```
 public inputValidator(event: any) {
    console.log('event.target'+event.target.value);
   // const pattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/; 
   const pattern   =/^(TEST|DUMMY)$/ ; 
    //let inputChar = String.fromCharCode(event.charCode)
    if (!pattern.test(event.target.value)) {
      event.target.value = event.target.value.replace(/[^(TEST|DUMMY)$]/g, "");
      // invalid character, prevent input

    }
  }
```

Comment: Create get fn() {} which match with regex, add this fn to formControl to ts file. i.e. this.fb.group({SiteId: ["", [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern(this.fn),
      ]]
});

Comment: means,i did not get you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create your own validator to test against this patterns, and then subscribe to `statusChanges` to check if value is valid or not, and then update the FormControl if it matches your regex.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
   // assuming you have a FormBuilder already in your component
   this.fb.group({ SiteId: ['', [Validators.required, customValidator]] });
   // subscribe to status changes to overwrite the value
   const siteControlSub = this.fb.get('SiteId').statusChanges.subscribe((status) => {
       const control = this.fb.get('SiteId');
       // if control is INVALID and has the custom error that we set, then replace the value
       if(status === 'INVALID' && control.hasError('invalidPattern')) {
         control.setValue(control.value.replace(/[^(TEST|DUMMY)$]/g, ""))
       }
   }
}

// custom validator function to check against a regex
customValidator(): ValidatorFn {
   return (formControl: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
      const value = formControl.value;
      const pattern   =/^(TEST|DUMMY)$/;
      if(value.match(pattern)) {
         return { invalidPattern: true } 
      } else if(!value) {
         return { required: true } 
      }
      return true;
   }
}
```

In your HTML:

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width" style="width:1000%">
    <input matInput id="SiteId" formControlName="SiteId" placeholder="Enter Site Id" type="text" />
</mat-form-field>
```